# Germany visa rejected because less funds

Tags: visas, germany, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, proof-of-funds

My German Visa is rejected due to insufficient funds. I applied to go with my wife and 3 year daughter. I have shown 8741 euro in my bank account. Our stay was for only 12 days and 11 nights.  Should I appeal? What will be the procedure and funds needed for the process. any chances for getting visa after showing more amount on my bank statement. Our nationality is Pakistani. We wanted to go for tourism in winter vacation

Comment: Please give us more details of what they said in the rejection notice.

Comment: There is no fixed amount of money required to get a Schengen visa for Germany, but the guideline is 45€/day/person, which sums up to 1620€ for three persons in 12 days. Since your account balance is well beyond that amount, I would assume that there might have been suspicious transfers to your account, making the consulate officer unsure wether the money is actually yours or if you have 'pimped' the balance by e.g. borrowing money. As DJClayworth already asked, this should have been explained in more detail in the rejection notice.

Comment: The Schengen visa refusal is a standardised form. Please add to your question, which reasons were ticked.

Comment: Aren't we a little quick on the close vote here ? This was asked just 4h ago, it's currently 2am in Pakistan

Comment: @blackbird57 No, we usually are not quick enough. If a question is not improved, it often attracts lower quality or even wrong answers, and this is what is prevented.

Comment: @blackbird57 The (developing) procedure with regards to visa refusal questions is to close as unclear if there is not enough detail on teh refusal. OP can edit a closed question as many times as they like, and reopening normally happens pretty fast once we get the required information. (I;ve once seen a visa Q closed **after** the required info was supplied, that was odd, but reopening happened within an hour or so anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the visa process is to let genuine tourists and business travelers in and to keep illegal immigrants out. Obviously no illegal immigrant would ever **admit** to being an illegal immigrant, so the consular officials look at the documents with the application.

- Do you have enough money for your planned trip *right now*? It would seem that you have enough, so that is not the problem. (Note that if you show more money on the bank statement, that raises the question where it came from. Officials know that sometimes people borrow money just to show a higher balance.)
- Can you *afford* to spend that much money on a two-week vacation? For that, the officials compare your income, your savings, and your likely expenses at home. They ask themselves if it is credible that somebody in your situation would spend several thousand € on a winter vacation with no financial return on the "investment". This could be the problem.
- To support the decision, the official looks at more evidence that you're not an illegal immigrant. Do you own real estate at home? Do you have a stable job situation?

I think that you have to show more steady income, not more savings.